# Non-symmetric compounds with more than one Chiral Carbon

Tags: organic-chemistry

If I have a compound which has non-symmetrical ends, and it has more than one chiral carbon, with no other stereocentres. 
Then can I say that all of these will be stereocentres, and so there will be 2^n isomers? Can you give an example where this is not true (if)?

Comment: If you have $n$ chiral carbons such that the overall symmetry of the molecule does not make any of them equivalent, then yes, it would be $2^n$.

Comment: Yes I mean if n is a big number and we can't check all isomers, then how can I tell? I mean, what kind of asymmetry should I look for in the molecule?

Comment: Why would you need to check all isomers to know there are $2^n$ of them (which you already knew before I said that)?

Comment: I mean, to check if any of them are equivalent. How do I do that?

Comment: Why, just find the [point group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_groups_in_three_dimensions) of your molecule, and you'll see that right away.